# Using Total Variation Denoising to Clean Accelerometer Data

Tags: matlab, discrete-signals, noise, denoising, total-variation

I know this is maybe a very basic question but I am doing this as a hobby and I can't find a solution to this problem.
Basically I am trying to remove some noise from data I am reading from an accelerometer. This is what I want to achieve ([Taken from Total Variation Denoising (An MM algorithm)](http://eeweb.poly.edu/iselesni/lecture_notes/TVDmm/TVDmm.pdf)):

[image]

I read in [Picking the correct filter for accelerometer data](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/3026/picking-the-correct-filter-for-accelerometer-data) that Total Variaton Denoising would fit my needs. So I read [Wikipedia - Total Variation Denoising](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_variation_denoising) article from Wikipedia and I think I have to use one of this equations:

[image]

[image]

But I don't understand how I apply this to my signal. Suppose I have a set of x,y points like in the plots above, how I apply the equation to that data? I implemented some simple low-pass and high-pass filters like this:

```
gravity[0] = alpha * gravity[0] + (1 - alpha) * event.values[0];
```

But this is maybe too complex and I don't know where to start or how. I want to implement this in Java or C so Matlab is not an option (I have seen a lot of MatLab implementing this). I will appreciate any help to guide me in the right direction!

Comment: In your graph your clean signal only has integer values. I suppose this is usually not the case, is it?

Comment: @MattL., I believe he took a graph from this publication: [link](http://eeweb.poly.edu/iselesni/lecture_notes/TVDmm/TVDmm.pdf).

Comment: Right! Great, I know the author personally, but I didn't know he also published on TVD! Thanks for pointing this paper out to me!

Comment: @Andres, I added MATLAB Code to solve the Total Variation Denoising problem. You may use it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apart from Total Variation Denoising you could try a first much simpler approach: a [median-filter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median_filter). You just move a window along your data and replace the current input value by the [median](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median#The_sample_median) of all data in the window. You just have to optimize the window length (by experimenting).

By the way, the equations you copied into your question are for 2-dimensional data, but your data are 1-D.

Answer (score 5):

Well, unless it is a more programming question (how to translate from MATLAB script to C code), you might find interesting the following implementation: [click](http://www.gipsa-lab.grenoble-inp.fr/%7Elaurent.condat/download/condat_fast_tv.c), proposed in this article: [A direct algorithm for 1D total variation denoising](https://lcondat.github.io/publis/Condat-fast_TV-SPL-2013.pdf).

Good luck!

Comment: +1 Condat's algorithm is great (and easy to port).

Answer (score 3):

If your data model is Piece Wise Smooth Signal then you should use Total Variation as regularization.

Let's try comparing 2 methods for Denoising with 2 different regularization (Both works on the Derivative of the Signal):

$$ \text{Toal Variation:} \quad \arg \min_{z} \frac{1}{2} {\left\| z - b \right\|}_{2}^{2} + \lambda {\left\| D z \right\|}_{1} $$

$$ \text{Tikhonov Regularization:} \quad \arg \min_{z} \frac{1}{2} {\left\| z - b \right\|}_{2}^{2} + \lambda {\left\| D z \right\|}_{2}^{2} $$

Where $ D $ is the finite difference method.

Both are pretty easy to solve (For small signals even simple Sub Gradient Method will do nicely).

### Results

[image]

[image]

As can be seen while the Tikhonov Regularization decays the noise (Using limiting the derivative) yet leaves a signal which isn't Piece Wise Smooth, the Total Variation Regularization works as intended and almost restore the signal perfectly.

The full code is available on my [StackExchange Signal Processing Q14968 GitHub Repository](https://github.com/RoyiAvital/StackExchangeCodes) (Look at the `SignalProcessing\Q14968` folder).